# Algorithms: Get final state of array after incrementing/decrementing elements based on neighbors

Tags: algorithm

> You're given an array of integers A. You keep doing iterations of the following until the array stops changing: if an element is larger than both of its adjacent neighbors, decrement it by 1. If an element is smaller than both of its adjacent neighbors, increment it by 1. Return the final state of the array (when it will not change any more). Note that the first and last elements do not have two neighbors, so they will never change.

Example: [1,2,7,4,6] -> [1,2,6,5,6] ->[1,2,5,6,6]

Example: [1,2,3,4] Does not change

Anyone have an idea of how to do this better than simulation? I feel like there should be an O(n) solution, but I can't think of it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include a specific language tag for the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate teh differnce between all numbers. For your series:

```
1 , 2 , 7 , 4 , 6 you get
  1   5   -3  2
```

you can conclude that a sign change from + to - means a decrease of the number and from - to + and increase

You also can conclude that 7 can be decreased `min(abs(5), abs(-3)) = 3`  times max before it "hits its boundry" what is 4. Problem is that 4 changes with the first iteration. This you can recognize by the 2 sequential sign changes. So when this is happening, your max before hitting the boudry for 7 becomes:  `min(abs(5), ceiling(abs(-3)/2)) = 2`
as the max of hitting the boundy on 4 becomes `min(ceiling(abs(-3)/2), abs(2)) = 2`
With the knowledge above, you know you need to deduct: 7 - 2 = 5 and increase 4 + 2 = 6 to get your answer.